# Position relative acting strange in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I am having problems with my two slides in Firefox. In Chrome it looks as it should but in Firefox the elements/images is positioned outside the browser. When I remove "position:relative" from the elements the position back in the browser but the dimensions of images is weird. Please see images below:

[image: This is how it looks like in chrome]

[image: This is how it looks like in firefox]

[image: This is how it looks like in firefox when "position:relative" is removed on the wrapper/container elements (div)]

Here is the markup for the black squares on the bottom of the page:

```
<div class="ca-item ca-item-<%=Featsitems %>">
            <div class="ca-item-main" style="border:2px solid #<%=_dis.FeaturedBorderColor %>">
                <a style="float: left;" href="<%=featNews.ElementAt(i).PageUrl %>">
                    <div class="Feat_Element" style="width: 181px; position: relative; height: 175px;">
                        <div style="width: 181px; height: 100px; border: none; float: left;">
                            <img src="Images/Page_Images/<%=featNews.ElementAt(i).Picture %>" style="width: 181px; border: none; height: 100px;" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 171px; float: left; font-size: 16px; padding: 5px 2px 2px 2px;">


                            <b><%=featNews.ElementAt(i).Title%></b>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 171px; float: left; border: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 0px 2px 5px 2px;">
                            <%=featNews.ElementAt(i).Text %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the markup for the big image

```
 <div id="SlideForm" style="height: 320px; display: block; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

My question is why is this happening? Is firefox handling position:relative that much different than chrome?

Comment: you need to post some code please.

Comment: dewd - I've updated the OP